# How should we handle data sorting in websocket api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, rest, websocket

We have a page built in ReactNative, which is showing live data using Websockets based api. We want to give option to sort the data depending upon the user selected field.

How should we do the data sorting ?

I could probably get these two approaches -

1. Whenever user clicks on some specific field in app screen, we will simply put the sorting key & value in array. The very next time we will get the data throuogh websocket, it will check whether that array is having value, if yes, it will simply sort the received data at client side & show it on frontend. This will simply add one more step before showing data in app.
2. In this approach, we will simply append the applied sort field & value in web socket request url, and then sorting will be completely handled by websocket api developer.

Please let me know which approach we should be going for ?

Answer (score 0):

Before using any of the above approaches, we will need to answers for below questions -

1. How frequently data is getting updated ?
2. How much data is api returning ?

If data is being updated very frequently, then we should be going with 2nd approach.
If api is returning very big amount of data, then we should be going with 2nd approach.

The combined answers will also effect the decesion.

I am open for suggestions.

Thanks